# Date and time settings disabled

Tags: system-settings

My date and time has suddenly become  1 jam 2013

In date and time preferences the setting "set date and time automatically" is disabled by which I mean it's greyed out. It's ticked and set to 10.2.0.90

How can I reenable this setting to change the date?

MacBook Pro with Mavericks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking you must be an administrator to change this setting. If you are using a non-admin account you can click on the lock at the bottom of the pref window and enter any admin credentials to enable the setting.

[image]

Comment: I am logged in as an admin and the lock symbol does not appear

Comment: Are you in a managed environment (school, office) or is this your own Mac?

Comment: Part managed (office)

Comment: In this case the Timeserver setting could be centrally managed which means you should approach your IT support person.