# Date and time unchangeable

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

My date and time on my Macbook is unchangeable, I have admin rights and it is my own laptop but am unable to select the option "set date and time automactically", my date is 17 days off and the time is off by 6 hours. Is there a terminal code to reset this? This [person](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/127353/date-and-time-settings-disabled) seems to be having a similar issue, but I also do not have a lock image.

Thank You very much,

Comment: Are you on a proxy by any chance?

Comment: Do you see the lock on any other preferences like Users & Groups and can you unlock it?

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot? Can you manually change time and date/define "unchangeable", is it greyed out, does it forget the setting as soon as the window is closed, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

YOU might have a problem with permissions..

- One is to restore system level permissions using the Disk Utility.
- and use  this for Home Folder to [restore them do following](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-quickly-restore-a-missing-admin-account-in-os-x/).:

> - Restart OS X and hold down the Command and R keys.
> - You will boot into the Repair Utilities screen. On top, in the Menu Bar click the Utilities item then select Terminal.
> - In the Terminal window, type “`resetpassword`” (without the quotes) and hit Return.
> - The Password reset utility launches, but you’re **not going to reset the password**. Instead, click on the icon for your Mac’s hard drive
>     at the top. From the drop-down below it, select the user account where
>     you are having issues.
> - At the bottom of the window, you’ll see an area labeled ‘Reset Home Directory Permissions and ACLs’. Click the Reset button there.
>
> The reset process takes a couple of minutes.

Comment: Good idea. But restoring permissions is much simpler. We don’t need to reboot. The easiest way is to launch Disk Utility and to choose to restore permissions.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco Good point but that will not restore the Home Folder (user)